# I get this error when doing "pod install" or "pod update" - better_player

Tags: flutter

I get this error when doing "pod install" or "pod update".

> Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 18116933e7
> (2 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700 Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
> Tools • Dart 2.14.4

```
razor@razor-MacBook-Pro ios % pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.8.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.8.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.8.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "better_player":
  In Podfile:
    better_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `better_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/better_player/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
razor@razor-MacBook-Pro ios %
```

Answer (score 2):

In PodFile uncomment the platform and update the version to 11. Then try pod install in ios directory. It should work.

Comment: Thanks this helped